# How to click an image button using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrapy, opencart, scrapy-splash

I am trying to crawl a multilanguage opencart website, which doesn't have direct link to its other language versions, which I need because I want to crawl it in all available languages. And it has set of javascript buttons that switch between the languages without changing the url. But when I access this website via crawler, it gives me only one language.

For crawling I use Scrapy in conjunction with Splash, so to my understanding I need to pass a piece of javascript code to my crawler to click button to change the language, and only then start to render the webpage in the language I need, for further parsing.

Here's the buttons code:

```
<div id="language" class="lang-opacity">
    <img class="lang-active" src="http://example.com/catalog/view/theme/theme_name/image/flags/ru.png" alt="Русский" title="Русский" onclick="$('input[name=\'language_code\']').attr('value', 'ru'); $(this).parent().parent().submit();">
    <img src="http://example.com/catalog/view/theme/theme_name/image/flags/ua.png" alt="Украинский" title="Украинский" onclick="$('input[name=\'language_code\']').attr('value', 'ua'); $(this).parent().parent().submit();">
    <img src="http://example.com/catalog/view/theme/theme_name/image/flags/en.png" alt="English" title="English" onclick="$('input[name=\'language_code\']').attr('value', 'en'); $(this).parent().parent().submit();">
    <input name="language_code" value="" type="hidden">
    <input name="redirect" value="http://example.com/" type="hidden">
</div>
```

here's the code of function itself:

```
function onclick(event) {
  $('input[name=\'language_code\']').attr('value', 'ru');
  $(this).parent().parent().submit();
}
```

So what kind of code should I pass to my crawler to switch a language for me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> «what kind of code should I pass to my crawler»

I assume you will pass it via the browser's console. Try:

```
$("input[name='language_code']").val("ru").closest("form").submit();
```

And just replace `ru` for the other language you need...